# Different UI based on who logs into the Android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

I am a beginner and I am trying to make a single application for two kinds of people (for example, say Professor and Student).

The professor will have all read and write permissions and the interface will have forms where professor can create announcements and save them, and also an activity which displays the previous announcements.

The students will have an interface and read-only permissions. They will be able to view the announcements from the professor (i.e. the student will have only the activity which shows all the announcements).

In the first screen of my application, I have a database of students and professors log in details.

My question is, can I have two different user interfaces for the application and only one of them shows up based on who logged into the application?

- If the professor logs into the application, then he should have two activities options one with the form and the other to display announcements.
- If student logs in, only the activity which displays the latest announcements.

Comment: Yes you can do it. use shared Preferences for this.While Login Store values in it like if it is Professor "P"  and for student "S". depending on this value show him your specified UI.

Comment: Yes, you can. Of course. Lots of applications do this. You can search for android tutorials yourself using tools like Google.

Comment: @user3390703 Did you get my approach?.

Comment: yes i guess i got what you told, is there a tutorial u can point me to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android Themes can be used for this pupose.

Refer: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: How can we achieve above scenario based on themes?

Comment: Set programatically setTheme(R.style.StudentTheme); when student login and in case of teache  setTheme(android.R.style.TeacherTheme);